# docker-compose.ymlで環境変数を扱いたい

Tags: docker

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948232/docker-compose-wont-find-pwd-environment-variable

ここにあるようにymlでは$pwdなどの環境変数が使えないようですが

いちいちユーザーごとに書き換えるのは非常に面倒です。具体的には

```
environment:
  NB_UID: 501
```

このUIDをdocker-compose upする人に逐一対応させたいです、つまり、

```
environment:
  NB_UID: $UID
```

としたいということです。何か方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: マニュアルを見る限り環境変数の使用はサポートされているみたいですが、実際に試してみましたか？ - 参考: [Compose ファイル・リファレンス - 変数の置き換え](http://docs.docker.jp/compose/compose-file.html#compose-file-variable-substitution)

Comment: エラーが出てバグるのが怖くてまだ試してなかったです！ありがとうございます！