# docker-compose.ymlでopenコマンドを使いたい

Tags: docker

```
version: "3"
services:
  jupyterlab:
    build:
      context: .
    user: root
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - "./work:/home/jovyan/work"
    environment:
      NB_UID: $UID
      GRANT_SUDO: "yes"
    command: start.sh jupyter lab --NotebookApp.token=''
```

これがyml何ですけどdocker-compose up -dでブラウザ起動まで一気に自動化させたいです

bashであれば複数のコマンドをcommandで使用可能のようですがこの場合どうすればいいかわかりませんでした。ちなみに `&& open localhost8888みたいな感じ` で加えてもダメでした

加えて、環境変数の `$UID` が読み込まれません、よろしくお願いします

Comment: 実行環境(OSの種類)も念のため明記してみてください。`open`コマンドは恐らくMacOS固有のコマンドです。 / 環境変数の話は [一つ前の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/53668/3060) で試した結果などをフォローアップしてください。

Comment: 実行環境はMacOSです。環境変数については何をすればいいのでしょう？